# What is the best solution when deleted the local working copy in git

Tags: php, git, bitbucket

I was working in local git folder and committing with bitbucket. Accidently the local copy was deleted. But I had the latest local copy without .git folder. So cannot commit now. The solution I know is deleting the local copy and clone again from bitbucket. But I want a better solution for this. What is the best solution using git commands for this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to migrate code to git from clearcase.And I think my solution will match your issue.
Just keep your local copy and clone a new one which you want to push to.

And then solution is here: copy the .git folder to your local copy folder. Try git status you'll find it works and then just commit what you want.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will meet your issue.

firstly enter your local copy dir,and execute below:

```
> git init
> git config remote.origin.fetch  +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git config remote.origin.url <YourUrl>
> git config branch.<branchname>.remote origin
> git config branch.<branchname>.merge refs/heads/<branchname>
> git pull
> git add .;git commit -am "****"  #Here commit your change, may you'll meet conflict issue.
> git push
```